# Django: is it better to run new site on new virtualenv or not?

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have one site on Django and it runs under VPS from virtualenv (let's call it VE). Now I need to launch another site on the same VPS and now I'm interesting what will be better: install my new site to VE or install new virtualenv for new site?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if offtopic or not...

Comment: Also, make a requirements file. http://blog.yourlabs.org/103518532

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New VE for each new project, unless you don't have any special reasons. Using one VE for all your projects is the same as not using VE at all. :-)

Answer (score 5):

If your new site will be using apps with different versions (as in VE) than it will be better to make another virtualenv and in this way you will be able to work on both sites by just activating related virtual env without making change to already using virtualenv.

Answer (score 3):

Create new virtualenv.

It may be also a good idea to use different linux and DB users for different sites. This may look like a burden and it *is* a burden if it is not automated. So automate all these steps :) E.g. with [fabric](http://fabfile.org).

Answer (score 1):

Use different VE's for different projects. Who knows if you will eventually need to change a package for just one project?

With separate VE's for each project you can ensure you will not mess the other project's environment.